# Unable to show the button in Microsoft Teams

Tags: json, outlook, microsoft-teams

For the json data below unable to show the button in Microsoft Team 
but that is work fine in Outlook. Anyone can help me solve this ? ty
Pls refer to the photo link below .

```
{"@type": "MessageCard",
                    "title": "System Alert",
                    "text" : "Network Error",
                    "themeColor": "E81123",
                    "potentialAction": [
                {
                "@type": "ActionCard",
                "name": "",
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "@type": "TextInput",
                        "id": "comment",
                        "title": "Enter your comment",
                        "isMultiline": "true"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                "@type": "HttpPOST",
                "name": "OK",
                "target": "https://ptsv2.com/t/ANA/post",
                "body": "comment={{comment.value}}"
                    }
                ]
    }

            ]
        }
```

[Microsoft Teams output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkVfS.png)
[Outlook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OIrz.png)

Comment: Please try putting in name value for action card ( "name": "test" ) . You could [MessageCard Playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) to test this by using Send Via Webhook button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try putting in name value for action card ( "name": "ActionCardName" )

```
      {"@type": "MessageCard",
                    "title": "System Alert",
                    "text" : "Network Error",
                    "themeColor": "E81123",
                    "potentialAction": [
                {
                "@type": "ActionCard",
                "name": "ActionCardName",
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "@type": "TextInput",
                        "id": "comment",
                        "title": "Enter your comment",
                        "isMultiline": "true"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                "@type": "HttpPOST",
                "name": "OK",
                "target": "https://ptsv2.com/t/ANA/post",
                "body": "comment={{comment.value}}"
                    }
                ]
             }

            ]
        }
```

You could [MessageCard Playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) to test this by using Send Via Webhook button.

Comment: Thanks for ur help... The button able to show in Desktop version but cannot show in Mobile app.